# How can I find the number of elements of a multidimentional dynamic array

Tags: c++builder

My pointer is declared in the header file:

```
int (*array)[10];
```

I pass a argument to a function that initializes the array:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Initarray(const int cnt)
{

    try
        {
        Form1->array = new int[cnt][53];
        }
    catch(bad_alloc xa)
        {
        Application->MessageBoxA("Memory allocation error SEL. ", MB_OK);
        }

    Form1->Zeroarray();
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I set all element of the array to "0":

```
    void __fastcall TForm1::Zeroarray()
    {
    __int16  cnt = SIZEOF_ARRAY(array);
    // Here is where I notice the problem. cnt is not correct for the size of the first level of the array. 
    if(cnt)
        {
        for(int n = 0; n < cnt; n++)
            {
            for(int x = 0; x < 53; x++)
                {
                Form1->array[n][x] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my defined size of array macro:

```
#define SIZEOF_ARRAY(a) (sizeof((a))/sizeof((a[0])));
```

When array is created with 10 elements of 53 elements `array[10][53]`
I get a return from `SIZEOF_ARRAY == 0`. It should equal 10.

I have tried several variation of this macro and just doing straight math with the `sizeof()` but I cannot get the correct output.
  What am I not doing?

Comment: Never mind, I did finally make the connection to other responses.

Comment: `new int[cnt][53]` is not valid syntax, and even if it were, your `SIZEOF_ARRAY()` macro (more specifically, `sizeof()` itself), cannot be used to determine the number of elements in a *dynamically* allocated array, only a *static* array.  `sizeof()` is evaluated at compile-time, but a dynamic array is allocated at runtime instead. For what you are attempting, you need to keep track of the number of elements you allocate. Better is to use `std::vector` or `System::DynamicArray` instead of a raw array pointer.

Comment: Thx for the insight!